# Having trouble while receiving data in database

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am trying trying to receive data by making a html form and then adding receiving data by $_GET method.Whenever I try to submit my data I get an error saying 'Your file was not found' in my chrome browser,so I tried opening my php page in chrome by typing "localhost/...." in my address bar and there it was displaying 'Database NOT Found'

here is my php code:-

```
<html>
<?php


$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "mysql"; //mysql is name of my database
$server = "localhost";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server , $user_name, $password,"addresbook");      //adressbook is where all the tabels are
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);


if (!$db_found) {

print "Database Found ";
$x=$_GET['fname'];
$y=$_GET['sname'];
$z=$_GET['address'];

$sql="INSERT INTO addresbook(First_Name,Surname,Address)     VALUES('".$x."','".$y."','".$z."')";
mysql_query($sql,$db_handle);

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found ";

}

?>
</html>
```

here is mt html code:-

```
<form action="practic.php"method="get">
Firstname:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Lastname:<input type="text" name="sname"><br>
Address:<input type="text" name="address"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

btw i am using wamp server.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`$db_found` will be true on success, so your condition should be

```
if ($db_found) { // make DB changes etc.
```

and switch to MySQLi or PDO and use prepared statements as already mentioned, refer to the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score -1):

use `mysqli_connect` because `mysql_connect` is now deprecated.

```
$db_handle = mysqli_connect($server , $user_name, $password,$database);
```

refer here for connection

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: Slightly short on detail. Especially as changing a `mysql_connect()` to a `mysqli_connect()` would necesitate changing **all other database access calls as well to make it work**

Answer (score -1):

Hi change your code to use `MysqLi` or use `PDO`

```
<?php


$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "mysql"; //mysql is name of my database
$server = "localhost";

$con =   mysqli_connect($server,$user_name,$password,'adresbook');//adresbook is where all the tabels are
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
// Change database to "adresbook"
$db_found = mysqli_select_db($con,'adresbook');


if ($db_found) {

print "Database Found ";
$x=$_GET['fname'];
$y=$_GET['sname'];
$z=$_GET['address'];

$sql="INSERT INTO addresbook(First_Name,Surname,Address)     VALUES('".$x."','".$y."','".$z."')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);

}
else {

    print "Database NOT Found ";

}

?>
```

Your `phpMyadmin` should look like this with the database `addresbook`  with a single `s`.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it gave me this error "Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown database 'addresbook' ".

Comment: @Pawan the error says there's no database called `addresbook`, the database doesn't exist or you misspelled the database name. If the database exists then it should be `addressbook` not `addresbook` .

Comment: I checked the spelling and it is addresbook.May be i am confusing with the name of database so here is what i am thinking name of data base is.when I login in from my phpadmin page at the left there are bunch of options out of which i selected mysql and and created a new data base name 'adresbook'.So here i am assuming that addresbook is name of my database.When I select that adresbook I have 4 tabels in it.(that is' ID','First_Name','Surname' and 'Address').So any idea what mistake I am doing.Thanks for replying :-)

Comment: See my updated answer with a screenshot at the bottom and I used `addresbook` with two `d`'s and yours has one `d` `adresbook`.

Comment: Ok I got my mistake I was thinking table as a database thanks for helping me in that.So now I have created a database named 'addresbook' but now it is saying me to create table so what name should i give to the table to match with code which you have given me above?btw thanks mate you are helping me a lot:-)

Comment: Name it `addresbook` and use that table name in your insert statement.

Comment: So now finally it is saying Database found.But now there is a new problem I  am searching this on internet from previous 1hr but cant find working solution.When i am submitting the data through my htmlform values are not getting stored in data base and after submitting browser is showing me the php code(exactly similar code which you gave me) and when i am opening my php page it says data base found but with 3 errors saying undefined index for 'fname','sname' and   'address'.Do you know anything about this?